# org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response no suitable HttpMessageConverter found

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, couchdb

I was fetching data from a CouchDB view using spring boot and everything worked fine, I then copy-and-pasted the json content provided by the view in a .json file and provided it in a URL using NodeJS and I know get the followin error message:

`org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class MyClass] and content type [application/octet-stream]`

Here is the line of code where the error occurs:

```js
RestTemplate myRestTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<MyClass> loadRecordResponse = myRestTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:4000/", MyClass.class);
```

Here is the code I use in NodeJS to create my REST web service:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   fs.readFile('D:\\Userfiles\\x\\Desktop\\Local CouchDB\\loads.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       console.log( data );
       res.end( data );
   });
})

var server = app.listen(4000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```